# I want to make an Album slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-slider

I am trying to make a song website and I have to make a song album slider just like you can see in this site [link](http://gaana.com/)

I have made the html css but I'm unable to slide it
[image]

The structure is:

```
<div id="slide1_container">


<img id="slide1_controls" class="left" src="img/left-arrow.png" >

<img id="slide1_controls" class="left" src="img/right-arrow.png">


 <div id="slide1_images">


 <div class="cus-panel-small panel radius mar-5 large-3 left ">[image1]</div>
 <div class="cus-panel-small panel radius mar-5 large-3 left ">[image2]</div>
 <div class="cus-panel-small panel radius mar-5 large-3 left ">[image3]</div>
 <div class="cus-panel-small panel radius mar-5 large-3 left ">[image4]</div>
</div>
</div>
```

There are total 12 images, 6 of them show at the start and the rest of them show one by one on clicking.

Comment: Please provide the **full code** in the question (or at least at jsFiddle.net or the like).

Comment: have you even linked in an jquery

Comment: i need jquery to slide it

Answer (score 1):

You can't really use html & css for that slider effect. 
Where's the jQuery?

Comment: dont even know how to take a start
  $('#slide1_controls').click(function(){

//var w=$("#slide1_images .panel:first").css("margin-left");

w=400;
 // alert(w);
$("#slide1_images").attr('style','margin-right:-'+w+'px !important');
  
 
  });